# Inappropriate datetime datatype and error on Flask App

Tags: python, html, datetime, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

## Background

What I would like to do is to implement a form to insert datetime with the specific data type (like 2019-10-23 22:38:18) on a web application written in Python Flask and SQLAlchemy.

complete image

```
 id |  name  | city    | datetime
----+--------+---------+---------
  1 | Hans   | London　|2019-10-23 22:37:10
  2 | John   | NewYork |2019-10-23 22:38:18
```

database

```
       List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------+-------+-------
 public | todos | table | username
```

## Problem

I've checked that inserting data for name and city column from forms was succeeded before adding datetime column and its form. But I'm stuck with the following error to insert datetime from the GUI form to the database.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

## Programs

### app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sys
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://username@localhost:5432/simplewr'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String) # Jon
    city = db.Column(db.String(120)) # New York
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime()) # 2019-10-23 22:38:18
    def __repr__(self):
      return f'<Todo {self.id} {self.name} {self.city} {self.datetime}>'

db.create_all()

@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
  error = False
  body = {}
  
  try:
    name = request.form['name']
    city = request.form['city']
    datetime = request.form['datetime']
    todo = Todo(name=name, city=city)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    body['name'] = todo.name
    body['city'] = todo.city
    body['datetime'] = todo.datetime
  except:
    error = True
    db.session.rollback()
    print(sys.exc_info())
  finally:
    db.session.close()
  if error:
    abort (400)
  else:
    return jsonify(body)


# Filters
def format_datetime(value, format='medium'):
  date = dateutil.parser.parse(value)
  if format == 'full':
      format="EEEE MMMM, d, y 'at' h:mma"
  elif format == 'medium':
      format="EE MM, dd, y h:mma"
  return babel.dates.format_datetime(date, format)

app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = format_datetime

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=Todo.query.all())
```

### index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Todo App</title>
<style>
  .hidden{
    display:  none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="/todos/create">
    <h4>name</h4>
    <input type= "text" name="name" />
    <h4>city</h4>
    <input type= "text" name="city" />
    <div>
    <label for="datetime">Date Time</label>
    {{ form.datetime(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM', autofocus = true) }}
    </div>
    <input type= "submit" value="Create" />
  </form>
  <div id= "error" class="hidden">Something went wrong!</div>
  <ul>
    {% for d in data %}
    <li>{{d.name}}</li>
    <li>{{d.city}}</li>
    <li>{{d.datetime}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
    <script>
      const nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
      const cityInput = document.getElementById('city');
      const dtInput = document.getElementById('datetime');
      document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = nameInput.value;
        const city = cityInput.value;
        const datetime = dtInput.value;
        descInput.value = '';
        fetch('/todos/create', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'name': name,
            'city': city,
            'datetime': datetime,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonResponse => {
          console.log('response', jsonResponse);
          li = document.createElement('li');
          li.innerText = name;
          li.innerText = city;
          li.innerText = datetime;
          document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(li);
          document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
        })
        .catch(function() {
          document.getElementById('error').className = '';
        })
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Environment

Python 3.6.0

Flask 1.1.1

SQLAlchemy　1.3.10

PostgreSQL 11.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using your `form` in quite and unconventional way. Not that its wrong, its just that it's different from the typical which makes `googling` for help more difficult.

Now on to your question...

The reason you are getting this error is because you haven't passed a `form` variable for your template to use. Your index route would look something like:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=Todo.query.all(), form=form)
```

However the above won't work because you haven't defined a form in your `index()` route. So you have to implement your `datetime` atttribute the same way you did for `name` and `city` inside your jinja template. Instead of:

```
{{ form.datetime(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM', autofocus = true) }}
```

you will need to create the html yourself. For example:

```
<input id="datetime" type="datetime-local">
```

you can look through the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) to see all the options you have for specifying a `datetime-local` input type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted a new question after editing my code following your advice. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552236/error-when-aquiring-date-time-data-on-flask-app